# How can I automatically convert % to px in JetBrains WebStorm?

Tags: html, css, webstorm

How can I see the measurements of a HTML element in multiple units?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your title and your question seem to be asking different things. In pure JavaScript you’d probably be looking at using getComputedStyle as a basis for the answer to the question part.

Comment: As I get it the person wants to have something in `%` percents and then see the equivalent of that in `px` (e.g. CSS `width: 20%;` = `width: 200px;`). The issue here -- the IDE does not see your live page layout like a browser does, so it cannot make such a conversion. Plus, it would also depend on the current device screen size / parent element dimensions etc... But if a conversion is deterministic (e.g. HEX color into RGB form) then it could be done in the IDE.